# Extending done() in jQuery's Promise object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I'd like to wrap `$.ajax().done()` in a separate class, which includes validation of JSON responses against a schema.

A sample call could look like this:

```
myService.get("/api/people").done(function(people) {
    // at this point I'm certain the data in people is valid
    template.render(people);
}).catch(function() {
    // this happens if validation of people failed, even if the request itself was successfull
    console.log("empty json or validation failed");
});
```

The success callback function is passed in `done()`, but should only be executed if a private function (`_validate(data, schema))` returns true. A less elegant version could look like this:

```
myService.get("api/people", successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I would like to expose the internal Deferred methods of `$.ajax()` directly. Is this possible?

Comment: You have a `GET` which could return invalid data? Am I missing something? That sounds crazy.

Comment: @Mathletics that's not crazy at all. _In the wild_ requests will randomly fail. For instance you will get only part of the body, you might get a 404 or 500 from the server or you might lose your connection.

Comment: `myService.get("api/people").then(successCallback, errorCallback);` ???

Comment: @Mathletics The JSON request itself might be successful, but I would like to validate the response object against a set of criteria.

Comment: @Halcyon but any of those cases would be a _request error_, and would trigger the appropriate handler. OP is saying the request will succeed, but the actual response might contain invalid data (not corrupt/bad data, just data that doesn't fit some schema on the client.)

Comment: @Mathletics then it's still a valid case to defend against. For instance if you update the server with new code you might break your dataset structure. The client expects the old format whereas the server already outputs the new format. In theory the client has no idea what the server is going to return. For many simple cases this is not something to worry about but you're building large scale applications this becomes important. Also a partial body is not a request error (Content-Length is not validated for you)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to change the `Promises`. You can use `then` to *layer* promises.

```
function _validate(data, schema) {
    return false;
}

var myService = {
    get: function (data) {
        return $.ajax(data).then(function (reply) {
            if (_validate(reply, schema)) {
                return reply;
            } else {
                // works if your library is Promises/A+ compliant (jQuery is not)
                throw new Error("data is not valid JSON"); // causes the promise to fail
                /*// else do:
                var d = new $.Deferred();
                d.reject("data is not valid JSON");
                return d.promise();*/
            }
        });
    }
}

myService.get("foo").done(function () { /* success */ }).fail(function () { /*failed */ });
```

Comment: When you `return` in a `then` that becomes the new result. This allows you to modify the result (like a pipe and filter) or fail the promise (by throwing an error).

Comment: Wouldn't calling `.done()` on the returned JSON cause an error?

Comment: What do you mean? `$.ajax()` returns a Promise, `$.ajax().then()` returns a Promise and thus `myService.get()` returns a Promise. They all have a `.done()` function. `.then()` doesn't return a value, it returns a Promise - it can't return a value because it's asynchronous, remember?

Comment: But by throwing unhandled error, the promise state is still `pending` right?

Comment: When you throw an Error in a `.then()`-callback the Promise is **rejected** with the error as it's result. The Error is caught. If you wouldn't catch it nothing would because it runs in the event loop of the ajax onreadystatechange.

Comment: @Halcyon Seems cool but i'm unable to replicate it, see e.g http://jsfiddle.net/Ld49brs7/  What i'm doing wrong? EDIT: more relevant example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld49brs7/3/

Comment: Sorry if i'm out of topic, i'm trying to understand how i could use your tip in a relevant way, if that makes sense

Comment: Here is one that does work. http://jsfiddle.net/Ld49brs7/4/ It seems that jQuery doesn't support throwing in then callbacks, instead you can return a failed promise.

Comment: @Halcyon: ahh, the joys of non-Promises/A+ compliant implementations... Yeah, jQuery doesn't catch thrown errors in `.then`, unlike most promise libraries.

Comment: @Halcyon I guess you meant `a failed deferred` in your last comment. Ya makes sense

Comment: @A.Wolff no. a _failed Promise_ is correct. A _Deferred_ is a construct invented(?) by jQuery. It exists to allows you to set up and reject/resolve a Promise. Other implementations are possible.

Comment: @Halcyon Oops sorry, i was talking getting the jQuery promise philosophy in mind where a 'promise' cannot be rejected or resolved manually. But you are correct, just as Quantas 94 Heavy indeed

Comment: @A.Wolff I see I did make a mistake that could cause confusion. I had `return d;` instead of `return d.promise();` I think jQuery has some magic where it converts a Deferred into it's associated Promise if a Promise is expected. Ah jQuery .. why you gotta be like this? Too much magic for me.

Comment: No, jQuery will not convert a Deferred into it's associated Promise if a Promise is expected. However, a `$.Deferred().then(...)` chain will return a Promise not a Deferred because `.then()` unambiguously returns a Promise - never a Deferred. Meanwhile, `.done()` unambiguously returns its input. Consequently `$.Deferred().done(foo).resolve();` is equivalent to  `$.Deferred().resolve().done(foo);` and `foo` will fire, but `$.Deferred().resolve().then(foo);` and `$.Deferred().then(foo).resolve();` are not equivalent - the latter will throw an error as a Promise has no `resolve()` method.

Comment: You can see the two behaviours [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vdymuwd/), A major issue with jQuery Deferreds/Promises is that their success/error callbacks are not guaranteed to be called in a future event thread. For comparison, try the Native Promise buttons in the same fiddle (in browsers equipped to run native Promises).

Comment: And to prove that jQuery *can* behave properly ... try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vdymuwd/1/)